# Mickey Mouse comic where there's a vivid picture of a bank being robbed and sunken into the ground, possibly including Pete or Phantom Blot

Tags: story-identification, comics, disney, mickey-mouse

I remember an old comic book from my early childhood (must be around the year 2000) which featured Mickey Mouse and other Disney characters, as well as scifi elements.

There's one feature that sticks out: Mickey traps Pete or Phantom Blot and their gangs from robbing a bank by opening a giant hole in the ground where the bank falls through, stopping them from leaving.

That's all I remember, but it's a very vivid scene. The ground opening up was a full page picture.

It possibly may have been the other way around - the bank was sank into the ground by Pete or Phantom Blot in order to trap Mickey and steal the money.

Comment: Where / in which language did you read it? Disney comics are published in many countries, and are often written and drawn by local artists.

Comment: @lfurini english

Comment: I am offering a 100 bounty on this whenever it gets answered.

Answer (score -4):

I believe what you're looking for is "Space Mickey and the Throgg Ray Wars," which appeared in [Disney Adventures Vol.2, #9](https://www.comics.org/issue/941891/).

Synopsis:

> Mickey, Minnie, and Goofy fly to the Caribbean to extradite Pete for robberies. On the way back their plane is kidnapped by a flying saucer and the four are taken to the planet Throgg. After an audience with the planet's ruler, (also named Throgg), Pete volunteers to obey the ruler, while the other three are sentenced to slavery. With the help of a spy, Mickey, Minnie, and Goofy escape in spaceships.

Comment: I'm not seeing any scenes that match the one in the original question. Can you explain why you think this is the correct answer?

Comment: Not this. Sorry